# sbt plugin - own configuration classpath incomplete

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to create a sbt plugin for a new kind of tests. To keep things simple I created a small fuzz test plugin, analog to the one mentioned in the [sbt docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Plugins-Best-Practices.html#When+to+define+your+own+configuration).

My plugin class looks currently like this:

```
package sbtfuzz

import sbt._, Keys._

object FuzzPlugin extends sbt.AutoPlugin {
  override def requires = plugins.JvmPlugin
  override def trigger = allRequirements

  object autoImport {
    lazy val Fuzz = config("fuzz") extend(Compile)
  }
  import autoImport._

  lazy val baseFuzzSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    test := {
      println("fuzz test")
    }
  )
  override lazy val projectSettings = inConfig(Fuzz)(baseFuzzSettings) ++ inConfig(Fuzz)(Defaults.compileSettings)
}
```

The only thing I added in comaprison to the code in the docs is the `inConfig(Fuzz)(Defaults.compileSettings)` to the get tasks to compile the code.

If I execute `sbt fuzz:compile`, sources in `src/fuzz/scala` are compiled. But if the sources have dependencies to the actual project code ( like all tests have) the compile failes, because the classes were not found. I guess it's because the `fuzz:fullClasspath` only has one entry:

```
[info] * Attributed(.../fuzz/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/fuzz-classes)
```

whereas `test:fullClasspath` has the project classes as well as the dependencies in it:

```
[info] * Attributed(.../fuzz/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/test-classes)
[info] * Attributed(.../fuzz/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes)
[info] * Attributed(~/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.10.4.jar)
[info] * Attributed(~/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-sbt/sbt/jars/sbt-0.13.13.jar)
...
```

This way `test:compile` is able to compile the test classes successfully and `fuzz:compile` not.

How can I configure my `fuzz` configuration the way like the `test` configuration is, including all project dependencies?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
I found a (in my opinion) rather dirty workaround:

```
lazy val baseFuzzSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
  fullClasspath in Fuzz ++= (dependencyClasspath in Test).value,
  dependencyClasspath in Fuzz ++= (dependencyClasspath in Test).value,
  ...
)
```

With this I can compile my fuzz classes successfully. Is there a more sane way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For test configs, use `Defaults.testSettings` and `Defaults.testTasks`. Note that order matters:

```scala
inConfig(Fuzz)(Defaults.testSettings ++ Defaults.testTasks ++ baseSettings)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work, I still only have the `fuzz-classes` in my classpath. I changed the `autoImport` to extend from `Test` and changed the project settings to `override lazy val projectSettings = inConfig(Fuzz)(Defaults.testSettings ++ Defaults.testTasks ++ baseFuzzSettings)`.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to call `configs(Fuzz)` in your project's `build.sbt` file. I'm not sure how to do that via settings.